# What issues could arise when using GCD dispatchAfter() in this use case

Tags: macos, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

I'm going through a book on OS X programing as a refresher and have a document app set up with an array controller, tableView etc.  The chapter calls for implementing undo support by hand using NSInvocation.  In the chapter, they call for adding a create employee method and manually, adding outlets to the NSArrayController, and connecting my add button to the new method instead of the array controller.

Instead I did this with my method for inserting new objects:

```
-(void)insertObject:(Person *)object inEmployeesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
NSUndoManager* undoManager = [self undoManager];

[[undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self]removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex:index];

if (![undoManager isUndoing]) {
    [undoManager setActionName:@"Add Person"];
}
[self startObservingPerson:object];

[[self employees]insertObject:object atIndex:index];
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Wait then start editing
    [[self tableView]editColumn:0 row:index withEvent:nil select:YES];
});
```

}

This works ok (looks a bit silly), but I was wondering the what issues could arise from this.  I've done this elsewhere in order to execute code after an animation finished (couldn't figure out a better way).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you delaying the invocation of `-editColumn:row:withEvent:select:`?

Anyway, the risks are that something else will be done between the end of this `-insertObject:...` method and when the dispatched task executes. Perhaps something that will change the contents of the table view such that `index` no longer refers to the just-added employee.

Comment: The method still returns before the code in the block is executed doesn't it?

Comment: "Still"? I'm not sure what you're referring to. Yes, if you use `dispatch_after()` or `dispatch_async()` to dispatch a task, then the caller proceeds without waiting for that task to complete.

Comment: "Why are you delaying the invocation of -editColumn:row:withEvent:select:?"  It seems that my array controller isn't updating the table view isn't updating the table view until sometime after the method returns, that's why i'm playing with dispatch_after.

Comment: What's calling this `-insertObject:...`? It is documented that `NSArrayController` methods such as `-add:`, `-insert:`, and `-remove:` defer their results. However, if you're directly manipulating the model, the array controller should reflect the changes immediately, although I wouldn't expect that until *after* the insertion is completed. I would move the things you're trying to do here to the controller method(s) which are manipulating the model. It's not really appropriate for the model to do these view manipulations anyway.

Comment: This is all within a NSDocumentController subclass.  I was just playing around with it in order to avoid having to subclass the array controller in order to override the insert: method.

Comment: Also the add button in my ui is connected to the array controller's add method.

Comment: If you want custom behaviors when objects are added/inserted, I would direct those actions to the document controller (not in the property accessors). There, you should use the array controller methods which are synchronous (e.g. `-addObject:` rather than `-add:`) and then initiate the editing.